# Delete duplicates and keep one with condition in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server.

I have a table with the following design:

```
ID bigint
Number varchar(50)
Processed int
```

I have a lot of duplicates in the Number column

I want to delete all repeated Numbers, and keep the Number `where processed=1`

For Example if I have

```
Number --- Processed
 111   ---   0
 111   ---   0
 111   ---   1
```

I want to delete all and keep **the last one**

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Will you have any rows where the number is only there once and it is not processed? Or can you simply delete everything where processed = 0?

Comment: @Tanner I might have duplicates where processed=0. I want to keep at least one of all the duplicates, but if they have one with processed=1 the priority will be for that row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just trying to delete the rows where number equals 111 and processed does not equal 1 you can do:

```
delete from <table>
where
 Number = 111 and
 Processed <> 1
```

Assuming the ID is sequential and you want to keep the last row for each Number you can do:

```
delete from <table> t
left join (
    select
        MAX(ID) filter_ID
    from <table>
    group by
        Number
) filter on
    t.ID = filter.filter_ID
where
    filter.filter_ID is null
```

to keep at least one row per Number giving priority to Processed = 1

```
delete from <table> t
left join (
    select
    ID
    from (
        select
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY 
                    Number
                ORDER BY
                    Processed DESC,
                    ID DESC
            ) last_R,
            ID
        from <table>
    ) filter
    where
        last_R = 1
) filter on
    t.ID = filter.filter_ID
where
    filter.filter_ID is null
```

Comment: There are more than 500 000 duplicated numbers. I might have duplicates where all processed=0. I want to keep at least one of all the duplicates, but if one of them is with processed=1 the priority will be for that row.

Comment: you can reverse the ID order to ASC if you want the first entry where processed = 1

Answer (score 2):

Here is one method:

```
with todelete as (
      select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by number order by processed desc) as seqnum
      from table t
     )
delete from todelete
    where seqnum > 1;
```

The `row_number()` enumerates the rows, using the processed as a priority.  The logic ensures that exactly one row remains, even if none have `processed = 1`.

Comment: +1 I like this approach. easy and efficient. I checked it here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/925725/4

Comment: nice one Gordon, i did the same logic with the row_number but i guess i over complicated the overall syntax

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would approach this problem:

```
DECLARE @NUM VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @TAB TABLE
(
    NUMBER VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @TAB
SELECT number, from <table> where processed = 0 GROUP BY number HAVING COUNT(number) > 1

DECLARE @IDToKEEP TABLE
(
    id INT
)

WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @TAB) > 0
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @NUM = number FROM @TAB

    INSERT INTO @IDToKEEP
    SELECT TOP 1 id FROM <table> WHERE number = @NUM

    DELETE FROM @TAB WHERE number = @NUM
END

DELETE FROM <table> WHERE processed = 0 AND number IN (SELECT number FROM @TAB) AND id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM @IDToKEEP)
```

Comment: I might have duplicates where all processed=0. I want to keep at least one of all the duplicates, but if one of them is with processed=1 the priority will be for that row.